# Customize Android Phone.apk

Tags: android

I have been programming Android apps for quite some time, and my client asked if we could hide the telephone number on dialing screen when phone.apk is making a call.

I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me what is the best approach for doing this.  Should I make the changes in the phone.apk or any easy to update the phone layout so to hide the phone number when dialing.

Thanks in advance & I'd appreciate your help

Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

I think best thjng to do is just change the color of the fonts that matches the background. So this way you dont have to make lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i do not know the answer to this but I could propose a couple of ideas. I mean, the `phone.apk` is really not meant to be modified heavily once installed. One motivator for modifying phone.apk is say for mere replacing of some graphics and simple stuff like that. But you could try the following maybe:

1. First, get `phone.apk` from the phone
2. Rename it to `.zip`
3. Find the `.xml`
   resources (in the `/res/` folder) that draw the calling
   screen and look for the part you
   want to hide and add an
   `"android:visibility=invisible"`
   attribute to it's tag. I wouldn't suggest deleting it marking it as `"gone"` because it is probably referenced somewhere in the code

The other thing you could in theory do is, since Android is Open Source, you could get the Android source from the repository, change the part of code you desire and recompile it, but I doubt this is what you should advise your client to do :)

*Disclaimer: I have not tested this but both suggestions are fairly straightforward and easy so if you are unsure of how to do go trough with them please better don't or you could be spending the next few hours repairing the damages. Or try them on the emulator first :)*

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need search information about xposed framework, and with [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/what-is-xposed-framework-for-android-how-to-install-it-guide/) you can start.